# Macro is outlined with an error in visual studio but it still woks anyway. The error doesn't seem to make sense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I made a macro to call `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`, and VS keeps saying that there's an error whenever I call it, but it works anyway. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

#define DIM 30
#define TEMPO_ATTUALE chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
```

and here's the error that pops up when I try to call the macro:

`class "std::chrono::steady_clock" has no member "now"`

The thing is, I'm not using steady_clock, I'm using `high_resolution_clock`.

What's the problem here?

Comment: I am not getting the error you describe, nor any error/warning at all, even on Warning Level 4 and Treat Warnings as errors. However, my answer explains why you are seeing a mention of `steady_clock` instead of `high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: So it's just a local mistake from Visual Studio that happend for unknown reasons?

Comment: It depends. What version of Visual Studio are you using? You don't mention it in your question nor have your question tagged with a specific version.

Comment: @Casey The problem fixed itself by doing literally nothing, so yeah, it was a local random VS bug.

Comment: Unfortunately that means the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is an implementation defined `typedef` for one of the other two clocks: `steady_clock` or `system_clock`.

It's not a real type.

MSVC defines `high_resolution_clock` as `using high_resolution_clock = steady_clock;`.

This is why the error reports it as `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

Because it is implementation defined, it is preferable to just declare which clock you want to use; in this case, `steady_clock`.